# Is it possible to invalidate or delete a particular user's session data in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, database

Okay, so for my senior design project I am working with a group on an Node.JS / Express application for an SGA student volunteer program. We are using MongoDB for persistence along with the session store in Express.

- When a user signs in, their document is copied into their session storage.
- Anytime user data is modified, it is written to the MongoDB database. If the database update is successful the user session is updated with the new document in the database resulting from the update.
- Anytime user data is requested, it is read from the session store.

This works as long as the session stays updated every time user data is successfully modified in the database. It also lets us avoid having to read from the database every time we render a view with some user data.

We have different types of users. We have student `volunteer` type users, different levels of `staff` type users. I didn't think we would have a problem with the session/database combination until my partner implemented the functionality for the top-level `staff` type users. They have the ability to modify the data of the student `volunteer` users.

This is not a problem when it comes to writing to the database, we simply write the modified data to the volunteers document. The problem comes from the fact that, as far as I know, we have no way to update/invalidate/delete the `volunteer` user's session in response to a request from a `staff` type user to modify it.

Basically, if a `staff` user modifies a `volunteer` user's data and the `volunteer` user *is not* signed then everything works fine, the modification will be made and the `volunteer` document in the database will be modified. When the volunteer signs in this modified data will be read from the database and stored in the user's session.

However, if a `staff` user modifies a `volunteer` user's data and the `volunteer` user *is* signed in then there could be problems. The `volunteer` document in the database will be updated, but the `volunteer` user's session will not be updated until either the session has ended and the user signs in again causing their document to be read into their new session from the database, or until the `volunteer` user modifies their data causing their session to be updated with the new data from the database (this possibility may or may not overwrite the changes the `staff` user made).

Needless to say this has the potential to cause inconsistencies if not addressed. Does anyone have any advice on how I can deal with this. Is it not possible to use the session store as planned if we are going to allow one user to update another's data?

Is it possible to invalidate/delete a particular user's session in response to a different particular user's request? Or possible to modify a particular user's session in response to a different particular user's request?

**EDIT:** 
Not sure how this is off-topic, perhaps a little too focused and possibly without 'minimal understanding', I'll attempt to rectify that by adding some more to clarify my question:

```
function updateUserDocument(req, res, id, callback) {
    var data = req.body;
    var query = { _id: id };
    var cmd = {
        $set: {
            role: 'volunteer',
            volunteer: data
        }
    };
    var opt = { w: 1, new: true };
    users.findAndModify(query, null, cmd, opt, function (err, updated) {
        if (err || !updated) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, updated);
        }
    });
}
```

This is what is used both when a `volunteer` updates their own data, as well as when a `staff` user updates the `volunteer` user's data, the difference being that when the volunteer updates their data, the updated document passed back in the callback is used to update the session (I use the underscore merge method)

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    volunteerUpdateVolunteer: function (req, res) {
        updateUserData(req, res, req.session.user._id, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(400);
            } else {
                // save user session with updated document send success response
                _.merge(req.session.user, doc);
                res.send(200);
            }
        });
    },

    staffUpdateVolunteer: function (req, res) {
        updateUserData(req, res, req.params.id, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(400);
            } else {
                // no way to update the volunteer user's session here?
                // how can I handle possible inconsistencies?
                res.send(200);
            }
        });
    },
```

As our project is designed so far, this is my problem. I don't think that the session can be kept updated this way but I am not sure. Is there a way to keep the session updated? Or are we just using it all wrong?

Comment: If this is going to be closed immediately after it was opened because I'm not deemed to have a 'minimal understanding' of the problem I'm trying to solve; then it would be nice to be enlightened and have my apparently obvious conceptual misunderstanding of the problem corrected by the person who apparently does have the minimal understanding needed. I honestly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking into the [code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js), I wrote below snippet, hope it could be helpful

```
    var express = require('express');

    var sesseionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore();

    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'a4f8071f-c873-4447-8ee2',
        cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
        store: sesseionStore
    }));


    var volunteerid2sessionid = {

    };

    express.use(function (req, res, next) {
        volunteerid2sessionid[req.session.user._id] = req.sessionID;
        next();

    });


    /// working with volunteer sesseion
    // seems volunteerid is req.params.id in staffUpdateVolunteer
    sessionid = volunteerid2sessionid[volunteerid]; 
    sesseionStore.get(sessionid, function(err, sess){

    });
```